# MouseListener not giving accurate mouse location

Tags: java, mouselistener, mousemotionlistener

I am attempting to have a circle appear on the screen and follow the mouse around.  (Eventually I'm going to turn it into a game with ray casting)  I am using a MouseMotionListener and am trying to use the mouseMoved method to get accurate mouse location within my JPanel.  The problem is though that the farther I move my mouse down the screen, the less accurate it becomes.  By the time my mouse gets to the bottom, it is drawing circles about 20 pixels above.  It is not a lagging thing because it never catches up, it is always a few pixels above where it should be.

I've tried using different methods that call from MouseEvents and have tried using MousePointerInfo but none work correctly.  It does seem to work when I have the JFrame set to undecorated, but obviously that does not look good for a program and thus I want to avoid that.

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Moonlight");
        frame.setSize(700, 700);
        frame.setLocation(350, 50);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(new MoonlightPanel());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}


public class Panel extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage myImage;
    private Graphics myBuffer;
    private Timer t;
    public Panel () {
        myImage = new BufferedImage(700, 700, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        myBuffer = myImage.getGraphics();
        t = new Timer(0, new Listener());
        t.start();
        addMouseMotionListener(new Mouse());
    }

    private class Listener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            drawBackground();

            /*try {
                Point pos = getMousePosition();
                myBuffer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                myBuffer.fillOval(pos.x - 10, pos.y - 10, 20, 20);
            }
            catch(NullPointerException en) {}*/

            repaint();
        }
    }

    private class Mouse implements MouseMotionListener {
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            Point pos = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
            System.out.println(pos);
            myBuffer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            myBuffer.fillOval(pos.x - 10, pos.y - 10, 20, 20);
        }
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {}
    }

    public void drawBackground() {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have a mistake in the code you posted. `public class Panel extends JPanel`. Shouldn't that be `public class MoonlightPanel extends JPanel` ?

Comment: Your expectations and reality don’t match, the faster you move the mouse, the less events you will get and the further apart the points will become. A better solution might be to track all the points in a list and simply draw a line between each dot in sequence

Answer (score 1):

Your code is much more complex than it needs to be. The `Panel` class members are unnecessary. All you need to do is save the mouse location in the `mouseMoved()` method - in a class member variable - and reference it in the `paintComponent()` method to draw your blue circle. The below code is a stripped-down version which displays a blue circle that follows the mouse pointer around on the screen.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MoonLite extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener {
    private Point pt;

    public MoonLite() {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        pt = e.getPoint();
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (pt != null) {
            g.fillOval(pt.x - 10, pt.y - 10, 20, 20);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Moonlight");
                frame.setSize(700, 700);
                frame.setLocation(350, 50);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setContentPane(new MoonLite());
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This will draw a moving dot, instead of a line of does, which seems to be what the op is trying to achieve

Comment: The question states: _I am attempting to have a circle appear on the screen and follow the mouse around_ which gives me the impression that the OP's intention is **not** to have a line of dots.

Comment: Okay, then it’s got me scratching my head over why they should use a BufferedImage which isn’t going to be cleared. If that is the intended outcome for the op then  to you 

Comment: The original code posted by the OP gave me the impression that he was experimenting and guessing in order to get the desired result. That's why I offered a stripped-down version, rather than adjusting the original code. I think we need to wait for him to confirm my assumptions.

Comment: The proposed cut down code works as I wanted it to.  When I first learned Java, I was taught to use BufferedImage.  What is the point of the EventQueue and the run method?  I took out the implementation of that but left the JFrame and it still worked.

Comment: _Swing_ code runs on a separate, dedicated `Thread` known as the _Event Dispatch Thread_ (or EDT for short). If I remember correctly, somewhere in the code of class `JFrame` the EDT is launched. Executing static method `invokeLater()` of class `EventQueue` also launches the EDT and the parameter to method `invokeLater()` is an object that implements interface `Runnable`.